# Elasticsearch | Use of "docvalue_field" in a search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Going through this documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-docvalue-fields.html

I'm trying to find out a real use case as why one would need the docvalue_field as part of the query? Already these are part of the source and can it not be achieved by means of source filtering ("_source": ....) if we're interested in specific fields?

Answer (score 1):

Performance when querying nested documents is significantly affected by whether you enable `_source`. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits-source